# How to write a query so that I can insert a row based on another row value

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, case, sql-insert

Can someone help me please to frame a SQL query so that I can insert a new row based on CONDITION. Say if there is any row with a **Property** as "**`Name`**" then I need to insert a new row
PROPERTY, VALUE --> ("Boss",  "Is present")
else PROPERTY, VALUE -->("Boss", "Is Absent"). Kindly note that I don't want to use "dual" table as I am not using oracle DB. Thank you in advance.
Below is my *DB table* structure.

[image]

EDIT 1: Property is the primary key.

Comment: What if there are two rows whose property is `Name`?

Comment: Property is the "Primary key" in this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression and an `exists` condition:

```
insert into mytable (property, value)
select 'Boss',
    case when exists(select 1 from mytable where property = 'name') 
        then 'isPresent' 
        else 'isAbsent' 
    end
from dual
```

Comment: Thank you for response, I am getting "SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: @AshishBurnwal: so you are running oracle. Just add `from dual` at the end of your query, as in my updated answer.

Comment: Can we make it DB agnostic please? Because my application is not tightly coupled to Oracle DB.

Comment: @AshishBurnwal: I don't think that's possible in this case. The SQL language is vendor-dependent by nature, which is reflected here in this query.